# Ubuntu server - port forwarding

Tags: port, iptables, portforwarding, ubuntu-server

I need to redirect http port `80` to port with specific page, which running on port `9090/somepage`.

So in short:

Need redirect `x.x.x.x:80 -> x.x.x.x:9090/page`

I tried to do by command `iptable`, but I not be able to redirect port to specific port and page (only port to another port).

Please how I can realize this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an proxypass in the virtualhost to redirect it. For Apache:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html